# WordPress admin_notices notification displays at the wrong place

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add notification and error messages to my WordPress plugin.
Using the admin_notices hook, my code looks like this:

```
<?php
//Define notifications
function customer_admin_notice($message_type, $customer_nr = "") {
    if ($message_type === 'customer_update_success') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'Customer updated successfully.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else if ($message_type === 'customer_new_success') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'Customer added successfully.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }  else if ($message_type === 'customer_delete_success') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'Customer with number ' . $customer_nr . ' has been deleted.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else if ($message_type === 'customer_delete_error') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'No customer with number ' . $customer_nr . ' was found.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'customer_admin_notice');
?>
```

The notification get's printed, but it looks like this:
[Notification shows full width and behind side panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqaqv.png)

I've also noticed, that the notification get's attached directly under the body tag, unlike other notifications that are attached to wpbody-content:
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRKIv.png)

Does anyone have an idea why the notifications are not displayed properly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems admin_notices hook is fired before the wpbody-content container is rendered. Here's the updated code that should work correctly:

```
<?php
//Define notifications
function customer_admin_notice($message_type, $customer_nr = "") {
    if ($message_type === 'customer_update_success') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'Customer updated successfully.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else if ($message_type === 'customer_new_success') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'Customer added successfully.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }  else if ($message_type === 'customer_delete_success') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'Customer with number ' . $customer_nr . ' has been deleted.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else if ($message_type === 'customer_delete_error') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'No customer with number ' . $customer_nr . ' was found.'; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

function customer_admin_notice_wrapper() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    do_action( 'customer_admin_notices' );
    echo '</div>';
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'customer_admin_notice');
add_action('customer_admin_notices', 'customer_admin_notice_wrapper');
?>
```

It might help you to resolve this!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I tried it, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Oddly enough, '<div class="wrap">' doesn't get printed at all.

Comment: I added "echo '<script>console.log("test");</script>';" to the customer_admin_notice_wrapper function to check if it gets fired and it works, so I have no idea why it ignores the wrap div.